# Perl regexp to match random character/number combination?

Tags: regex, perl, numbers, character

I'm trying to match patterns like these with perl regexp:

```
_b04it4_
_bg4n5p_
_qp9bp_
_hp32z7_
```

...that is, underscore followed by some combination of characters and numbers.
I guess the "rule" is that there are >=1 [a-z] characters and >=1 [0-9] character/number, and no spaces, "mixed in any combination", between two underscore-characters.

And want to replace this with something, eg. "_X_". 
I'd appreciate some help with this .. My own attempts are looking horrible and don't work very well :)

Comment: Match `_[a-z0-9]+?_`?

Comment: how about `_([^_]+)_` ?

Comment: then what about `A` or `¿`? those would match...

Comment: @tenub -Yes true, those would match.. Per the OP's "rules" yours would be more accurate.  :)

Comment: @tenub, that one does not check that a-z AND 0-9 are present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way without lookaheads:

```
_([a-z]+[0-9]|[0-9]+[a-z])[a-z0-9]*_
```

Answer (score 3):

For at least 1 letter and number:

```
_(?=[^_]*[a-z])(?=[^_]*\d)[a-z\d]+_
```

[RegExr Example](http://regexr.com?383af)

`(?=[^_]*[a-z])` checks for the presence of a letter between the two `_`

`(?=[^_]*\d)` checks for the presence on a number between the two `_`

`_[a-z\d]+_` does the actual match

Comment: This can be simplified slightly if you don't need to match the pattern in the middle of strings e.g. `_123abc_` in the input `yo _123abc_ other 123 words`

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
_(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])[0-9a-z]+_
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is easily solved if you separate the conditions into multiple regex's.  The first matching the basic constraints, and the 2nd to ensure that at least 1 char and 1 digit are in the match.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my $before = my $after = $_;

    $after =~ s{_([a-z0-9]+)_}{
        my $chars = $1;
        # Require 1 digit and 1 letter in the match before replacing.
        ($chars =~ /[a-z]/ && $chars =~ /[0-9]/) ? "_X_" : "_${chars}_"
    }e;

    printf "%-12s -> %-12s\n", $before, $after;
}

__DATA__
_b04it4_
_bg4n5p_
_qp9bp_
_hp32z7_
_nonumbers_
_012345_
_1 space_
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
use strict;
my ($replacement, @input) = ('X', qw(_b04it4_ _bg4n5p_ _qp9bp_ _hp32z7_));
my @output = map {'_'.$replacement.'_'} grep {/^_[a-z0-9]+_$/ && /[a-z]+/ && /[0-9]+/} @input;
print "$_\n" foreach @output;
```